Unable to Access API After Renaming in WSO2 API Manager
I've recently changed the name of an API in WSO2 API Manager using the admin console. The name update appears to be successful in the publisher view, but when I click on the new name to open the API, it doesn't open.
Steps I followed:
Opened the WSO2 API Manager admin console.
Navigated to the specific API.
Changed the name of the API.
Saved the changes.
Now, clicking on the new API name does nothing. The API details do not load, and I can't manage the API through the console.

The reason for this is that the API name is not updated in the underlying database which is why the API details do not load when you click on the new API name
